# Отсортировать слова по алфавиту и вывести их

Tags: php

Нормальное ли решение?

Есть ли по лучше?

В моём решение, можно работать с массивом.

Дан текстареа и кнопка. В текстареа через пробел вводятся слова. По нажатию на кнопку выведите слова в таком виде: сначала заголовок 'слова на букву а' и под ним все слова, которые начинаются на 'а', потом заголовок 'слова на букву б' и все слова на 'б' и так далее. Буквы должны идти в алфавитном порядке. Брать следует только те буквы, на которые начинаются наши слова. То есть: если нет слов, к примеру, на букву 'в' - такого заголовка тоже не будет.

```
echo '
   <form method="get" action="">
       <textarea name="words" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
       <input type="submit" value="Отсортировать">
   </form>
';

if(!empty($_GET['words'])) {
    $alphabet = ['а', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'е', 'ё', 'ж', 'з', 'и', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'о', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'у', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ', 'ъ', 'ы', 'ь', 'э', 'ю', 'я'];


//$str = 'яблоко стул машина компьютер школа арбуз пельмени ключ душ мангал квартира сырость ананас';

$str = $_GET['words'];

$arr = explode(' ', $str);

sort($arr);

$values = [];

$i = 0;
foreach($alphabet as $chr){
    foreach($arr as $word){

        if(mb_strpos($word, $chr, 0) === 0) {
            $values[$chr][$i] = $word;
            $i++;
        }
    }

}

foreach($values as $letter => $val) {
    echo '<strong>Слова на букву ' . $letter . ':</strong><br>';
    foreach($val as $slova) {
        echo $slova . '<br>';
    }

    echo '<br>';

    }
}
```

Comment: вам не кажется, что просто перебирать все слова, и выводить заголовок, кода меняется первая буква будет проще? но  вашем случае можно применить `array_filter`  что несколько упростит код

Comment: @teran накидайте пример пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

[Вариант](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9138c1c1ebd5b8765e4e9e004b3e55065d09c920)

```
$str = 'яблоко стул машина компьютер школа арбуз пельмени ключ душ мангал квартира сырость ананас';

$words = preg_split('/\s+/', $str);
sort($words);

$values = [];
foreach($words as $word){
    $values[mb_substr($word, 0, 1)][]=$word;
}

foreach($values as $letter => $words) {
    echo '<strong>Слова на букву ' .mb_strtoupper($letter). ':</strong><br>';
    foreach($words as $word) {
        echo $word . '<br>';
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: стоит добавить ёжика и все сломается :D

Comment: @teran с чего вдруг?

Comment: ну не знаю, ваш ведь код :)

Comment: я лучше ежиков ловить буду чем писать алфавит